# How to know if textarea cursor reach to the last of the field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this example i want to add margin when cursor reach or touch send button and when touched the send button needed to add margin top. As same like current facebook comment field, when cursor touched sticker or emoji icon the icons are shifted to the bottom of fields.

```js
autosize($('textarea'));
```

```css
textarea { width:99%;min-height:15px }
div { position:relative }
button { position:absolute;right:10px;bottom:8px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jackmoore/autosize/master/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>

<div>
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<button>
Send
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for, try it out:

```js
autosize($('textarea'));

$("#send").on('click', function() {
  console.log("You clicked send!!");
  callSendFunction();
});

$('.textarea').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    console.log("You hit enter!!");
    callSendFunction();
  }
});

function callSendFunction() {
  console.log('Yay, we got it. Do something here..  ');
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 99%;
  min-height: 15px
}

div {
  position: relative
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 8px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jackmoore/autosize/master/dist/autosize.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
  <button id="send">
Send
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, you have a working demo above from my code. You can tweak it to your needs. Let me know, if you need help. And secondly, you shouldn't change questions once they have answers. People coming later on to check won't get the context.

Answer (score 0):

Hard wrap your text area to maximum

```
<textarea NAME="myTextArea"  ROWS="5" WRAP="HARD"></textarea>
<script>
var numCols = document.getElementById('myTextArea').cols;
document.getElementById('myTextArea').cols=numCols-7;
</script>
```